# Angular - Component Binding Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I have a component binding issue.  I'm pretty sure that I've got a syntax issue, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The full source code is available at https://github.com/TheMagnificent11/LunchVoting in the *feature/6_ExtendedInputBug* branch (https://github.com/TheMagnificent11/LunchVoting/tree/feature/6_ExtendedInputBug).  The *master* and *develop* branches have working code that doesn't use the *extended-input* component.

**input-error.component.ts**

This is the component that displays a form field error.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'input-error',
    template: './input-error.component.html'
})
export class InputErrorComponent {

    @Input()
    errorMessage: string;

    @Input()
    isError: boolean = true;

}
```

**input-error.component.html**

```html
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="isError">
    {{errorMessage}}
</span>
```

**extended-input.component.ts**

This is the component combines label, input and validation errors (collection of child components `input-error`) for a single form field.

```
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    ContentChildren,
    QueryList
} from '@angular/core';

import { InputErrorComponent } from '../input-error/input-error.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'extended-input',
    template: './extended-input.component.html'
})
export class ExtendedInputComponent {

    @Input()
    inputName: string = '';

    @Input()
    labelText: string = '';

    @Input()
    isError: boolean = false;

    @ContentChildren(InputErrorComponent)
    errors: QueryList<InputErrorComponent>;

}
```

**extended-input.component.html**

```html
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':border border-danger}">
    <label for="{{inputName}}">{{labelText}}</label>
    <ng-content select="input-control"></ng-content>
    <div *ngIf="isError">
        <ng-content select="input-errors"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controls.module.ts**

Module that has `extended-input` component

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ExtendedInputComponent } from './extended-input.component.ts';
import { InputErrorComponent } from './input-error.component.ts';

let components = [
    ExtendedInputComponent,
    InputErrorComponent
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: components,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ]
})
export class ControlsModule {
}
```

**register.component.ts**

This the form component that uses the other `extended-input` component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FormBuilder,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: './register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent {

    registrationForm: FormGroup;

    givenName: FormControl;

    surname: FormControl;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.givenName = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]);
        this.surname = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]);

        this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            givenName: this.givenName,
            surname: this.surname,
        });
    }

}
```

**register.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">

    <extended-input [inputName]="'givenName'" 
                    [labelText]="'Given Name'"
                    [isError]="givenName.touched && givenName.invalid">
        <input-control>
            <input type="text" formControlName="givenName" />
        </input-control>
        <input-errors>
            <input-error [isError]="givenName.hasError('required')">
                Given Name is required
            </input-error>
        </input-errors>
    </extended-input>

    <!-- The above components should produce HTML similar to this -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="surname" />
        <div [hidden]="surname.valid || surname.untouched">
            <span class="text-danger" [hidden]="!surname.hasError('required')">
                Surname is required
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">
        Register
    </button>

</form>
```

**Entry Module**

The module that contains `register` component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ControlsModule } from '../controls/controls.module';

import { RegisterComponent } from './register-component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: components,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ControlsModule
    ]
})
export class EntryModule {
}
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'inputName' since it isn't a known property of 'extended-input'.
1. If 'extended-input' is an Angular component and it has 'inputName' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'extended-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
        <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">

            <extended-input [ERROR ->][inputName]="'givenName'" 
                            [labelText]="'Given Name'"
                 "): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@9:28
Can't bind to 'labelText' since it isn't a known property of 'extended-input'.
1. If 'extended-input' is an Angular component and it has 'labelText' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'extended-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

            <extended-input [inputName]="'givenName'" 
                            [ERROR ->][labelText]="'Given Name'"
                            [isError]="givenName.touched && givenName.inv"): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@10:28
Can't bind to 'isError' since it isn't a known property of 'extended-input'.
1. If 'extended-input' is an Angular component and it has 'isError' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'extended-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. (""'givenName'" 
                            [labelText]="'Given Name'"
                            [ERROR ->][isError]="givenName.touched && givenName.invalid">
                <input-control>
               "): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@11:28
'input-control' is not a known element:
1. If 'input-control' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'input-control' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (""
                            [isError]="givenName.touched && givenName.invalid">
                [ERROR ->]<input-control>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="givenName" />
             "): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@12:16
Can't bind to 'isError' since it isn't a known property of 'input-error'.
1. If 'input-error' is an Angular component and it has 'isError' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'input-error' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
                </input-control>
                <input-errors>
                    <input-error [ERROR ->][isError]="givenName.hasError('required')">
                        Given Name is required
        "): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@16:33
'input-error' is not a known element:
1. If 'input-error' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'input-error' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
                </input-control>
                <input-errors>
                    [ERROR ->]<input-error [isError]="givenName.hasError('required')">
                        Given Name is requi"): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@16:20
'input-errors' is not a known element:
1. If 'input-errors' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'input-errors' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("input type="text" formControlName="givenName" />
                </input-control>
                [ERROR ->]<input-errors>
                    <input-error [isError]="givenName.hasError('required')">
       "): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@15:16
'extended-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'extended-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'extended-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">

            [ERROR ->]<extended-input [inputName]="'givenName'" 
                            [labelText]="'Given Name'"
 "): ng:///EntryModule/RegisterComponent.html@9:12
    at syntaxError (vendor.js:sourcemap:38524)
    at TemplateParser.parse (vendor.js:sourcemap:49621)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (vendor.js:sourcemap:63824)
    at vendor.js:sourcemap:63743
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (vendor.js:sourcemap:63743)
    at vendor.js:sourcemap:63630
    at Object.then (vendor.js:sourcemap:38513)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.js:sourcemap:63629)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (vendor.js:sourcemap:63558)
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: try with single quotes surrounding the string `[labelText]=" 'Given Name' "`

Comment: What happens when you use the suggestion above?

Comment: I still get "template parse errors"

Comment: It is worth noting that `import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/core'; @NgModule({providers: [FormBuilder]}) export ...` is an error. Providers are made available implicitly and transiently by the presence of their _providing_ NgModule in an `imports` array.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks for that.  However, I still get the same parse error.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think that was the root issue. Other's have pointed out that you should be writing `[labelText]="'Given Name'"`. They are correct. There is also a shorthand, `labelText="Given Name"` for binding to string literals. Also, note that `@Input('propertyKey') propertyKey` is redundant (just use `@Input() propertyKey` and makes Angular even uglier than it is already.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I implemented your changes and got a slightly different parse error.  The full source code is available here: https://github.com/TheMagnificent11/LunchVoting/tree/feature/6_ExtendedInputBug

Comment: @TheMagnificent11 that's a lot of code. Did you forget to import your own module perhaps?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, you had me second-guessing myself for a second.  `ExtenedInputComponent` is in the `ControlsModule`, which is imported in the `EntryModule`.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure transclusion of conditional elements is supported?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162266/discussion-between-themagnificent11-and-aluan-haddad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are declaring `extendedInputComponent` and `InputErrorComponent` in some other module(`ControlsModule`) than your `RegisterComponent` is declared(`EntryModule`) and `ControlsModule` is only imported in `EntryModule`, you have to export the Components also you declared in the same `ControlsModule`.

ie, your `ControlsModule` should be like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ExtendedInputComponent } from './extended-input.component.ts';
import { InputErrorComponent } from './input-error.component.ts';

let components = [
    ExtendedInputComponent,
    InputErrorComponent
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: components,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: components
})
export class ControlsModule {
}
```

Comment: There are other errors in my code but the missing export appears to be the major one

Comment: The first `ng-content` in `extended-input.component.html` should select an `input`, not an `input-control` (as there is no `input-control` component).  Similarly, there is no `input-errors` component (only `input-error`).  I need to either create one or change the way `extended-input` displays the validation messages.

Comment: why cant you select the `input` and `input-error` component the same way you do now

Comment: You can select `input`, but not `inpit-control`. I don't think you can select `input-errors` because such a component doesn't exist (only `input-error`... singular, no plural)

Answer (score 0):

`1. If 'extended-input' is an Angular component and it has 'inputName' input, then verify that it is part of this module.`

Make sure your components are imported properly. I noticed that the RegisterComponent has the 'Component' suffix at the end of the class name but the other ones, InputError and ExtendedInput, don't. Did you create one with the CLI but not the other ones? Maybe you forgot to import them into your module manually if you didn't use the CLI.

After that, there is an issue with property binding that I saw. It expects an expression inside quotes, so if you want to pass in literal text you need to have quotes inside quotes. It's weird. `[labelText]="Given Name"` is going to look for variables Given and Name, so it needs to be `[labelText]="'Given Name'"`. That's this error from above:

`[ERROR ->][labelText]="Given Name"`

Your app seems to have some other components `input-control` and `input-errors` but I don't see the code for those here, so couldn't get everything working on my end but that's a start. I can't completely follow the strategy with the ng-content/transclusion but that part of angular is not my forte.

Comment: I've made your suggested code change regarding component naming and added details of where to find the full source code (https://github.com/TheMagnificent11/LunchVoting)

Comment: Also, haven't use Angular CLI to create any of the code.  I used the ASP.Net Core Angular template and then changed the module structure.

Comment: I'm not an ASP.Net guy, so I can't debug it on my end. But I suspect when you changed the module structure is what caused the issue. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I think the module structure is mostly fine.  If I replace the `extended-input` component with regular HTML (and standard Angular Forms features), then it works.  `extended-input` is in its own module, so I'll add a bit more of the module code, which may help.